# AngularJS $compile doesn't remove double curly expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS is supposed to remove double curly braces **after** compilation. However, the removal doesn't happen in this case:

```
// testController is defined first
var html = "<div id='test' ng-controller='testController'>{{name}}</div>"; 
var $compile = angular.element("html").injector().get("$compile");
var link = $compile(html);
var content = link(angular.element("#view").scope());
$("#view").append(content);
```

`{{name}}` still appears in rendered HTML page. However, **the binding works**. For example:

```
var model = angular.element("#test").scope();
model.$apply(function (scope) { scope.name = "John Smith"; });
```

This will update the HTML, replace `{{name}}` with "John Smith".

If I don't use this dynamic method and just write the static HTML, AngularJS properly removes double curly expressions after compilation. Do I have to do something special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `$digest` or `$apply` on your scope after linking if it's an external event that's triggering your code.

e.g.

```
elem.click(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // code here
    });
});
```

Comment: In practice there's little difference, but it's good practice to wrap the handler to your external event in `$apply`, e.g. `elem.click(function() { $scope.$apply(function() { /* code here */ }); });`